# Fill a DropDownList into an ASCX control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu, viewmodel, viewdata

I want to fill a dropdownlist into an ASCX.
To do that, in the controler i use a LINQ query and fill the result into a viewModel.
Generate the dropdown is ok from the view but not from the ASCX !
Have you an idea of why this don't work ?

Thank's by advance :-)

**Code in controler**

```
var query = from foo in session.Linq<PROJECT.Models.bar>() select foo;
PROJECT.ViewModels.myviewmodel viewModel = new PROJECT.ViewModels.myviewmodel();
viewModel.data = new SelectList(query, "Id", "title");
return View(viewModel);
```

**Code in view**

```
<h2>Create</h2>
<%= Html.EditorFor(a => a.evaluation, new { EvaluationTypes = Model.evaluationTypes })%>            
<!-- Generate from here is ok -->
<%: Html.DropDownList("foo",Model.evaluationTypes) %>
```

**Code in ASCX**

```
<%= ViewData["EvaluationTypes"] %>    
<%: Html.DropDownList("foo", ViewData["EvaluationTypes"])%>
```

Comment: In view you use Model.evaluationTypes, but in ASCX you use ViewData["EvaluationTypes"]. Did you fill ViewData["EvaluationTypes"]?

Comment: @Pavel, yes he is passing it as second argument of the `EditorFor` helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you using a strongly typed Editor Template and abandon ViewData:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.evaluation) %>
```

and in the EditorTemplate:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.foo, Model.evaluationTypes) %>
```

---

UPDATE:

After you've posted your exception stack trace I've spotted the problem:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("foo", (SelectList)ViewData["EvaluationTypes"])%>
```

You need to cast to `SelectList` your `ViewData["EvaluationTypes"]`. This being said those ugly casts should be avoided by using strongly typed helpers as I suggested in my initial answer.

Comment: hm, in fact do a <%= ViewData["EvaluationTypes"] %> into the partial show me "System.Web.Mvc.SelectList", is that indicate that the data is being passed to the partial ?

Comment: So, have you an idea of the issue of this ? :-S

Comment: No, I am unable to reproduce the error. It works for me. Are you getting an exception or simply the list doesn't fill with any values?

Comment: Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<PROJECT.Models.bar>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: OK, got, it, see my update and next time always include exception messages in your questions. It makes the problem easily discoverable.